# $\iint 1/(x+y)$ in region bounded by $x=0, y=0, x+y =1, x+y = 4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\iint 1/(x+y)$ in region bounded by $x=0, y=0, x+y =1, x+y = 4$ using following transformation:  $T(u,v) = (u - uv, uv)$.
I want to make sure that my method is correct

Calculating the jacobian, I get $u$
since $x+y = u$, i get that $1 < u < 4$
Additionally, $v = y/y+x$ and thus at $x = 0$, we have $v = 0$ and 
at $y = 0$ we have $v = 1$.

So this the double integral is equivalent to
$\iint(1/u)u dudv$ over the area $[1,4]$x$[0,1]$ which is easily solved

I am not sure about the method I employed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats your region? {(x,y) | x > 0, y>0, x+y=1}? Or {(x,y) | x > 0, y>0, x+y=4}? Or [1,4]x[0,1] ? Please specify.

Comment: Yes, the method is totally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the method is correct, indeed we are considering the following change of coordinates

- $u=x+y \implies 1\le u \le 4$
- $v=\frac{y}{x+y}\implies 0\le v \le 1$

indeed for any fixed value for $u=x+y\,$ we have that $y$ varies form $0$ to $u$ and therefore $v$ varies from $0$ to $1$

[image]

the jacobian is

$$du\,dv=|J|dx\,dy=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\-\frac{y}{(x+y)^2}&\frac{x}{(x+y)^2}\end{vmatrix}dx\,dy=\frac1udxdy \implies dx\,dy=u\,du\,dv$$

and therefore

$$\iint_D \frac1{x+y}dxdy=\int_1^4\int_0^1\frac1u\cdot u\,du\,dv$$